# How to view your Steam Year in Review from your profile?

Tags: steam

I am unable to find a place where I can see the "My year in review" from my steam profile. I received a mail about it, and thought it was quite informative, and would like to compare this year's summary with last year's summary.

Is that possible?

**EDIT**

I have found the link in my email from last year, but not quite in the mood to reset my Steam password in my browser (my Steam client is permanently logged in - so can't remember the password). So - it would be nice to find this review in my profile. I can't see a way to paste the link in my Steam client  browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your profile and change your showcases which should include your "Steam Year in Review" as a showcase and include your previous years:

[image: showcases]

After doing that, you can click on the showcase from your profile to view it.

Another solution might be simply going to your profile and extracting your user ID from the URL (`<yourUserId>` in the below example):

```
https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/<yourUserId>/
```

Then, go to:

```
https://store.steampowered.com/yearinreview/<yourUserId>/<year>
```

If I input `2022` for the `<year>`, I can view it, and likewise `2023` for the `year` is this years. You will need to be signed in to Steam in the web browser for this to work, unless your review is public.

Additionally, you can also obtain this URL from the drop down on your username in the browser and then just change the year as desired:

[image: year in review dropdown option]

Note I could not find this same dropdown option in the Steam Application, only in the web browser.